# Grouping together Lists<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects (`Session`) that are potentially linked to each other via. a property (`ParentSessionId`)

```
public class Session
{
    public int Id;
    public int? ParentSessionId;
}
```

How can I 'group' together a list of all the Sessions with their 'children' sessions into 'collections'?

I think I might be over-complicating things with my attempt in code:

```
List<Session> shiftSessions = new List<Session>();
var cluster;

foreach (var s in shiftSessions)
{
    List<Session> familySessions = new List<Session>();
    List<Session> singleSessions = new List<Session>();

    if (s.ParentSessionId == null)
    {
        if (shiftSessions.Any(x => x.ParentSessionId == s.Id))
        {
            familySessions.Add(s);
            familySessions.AddRange(shiftSessions.Where(x => x.ParentSessionId == s.Id));
            cluster.Add(familySessions); //if cluster doesn't contain familySessions
        }
        else
        {
            singleSessions.Add(s);
            cluster.Add(singleSessions); //if cluster doesn't contain singleSessions
        }
    }
    else
    {
        familySessions.Add(s);
        familySessions.AddRange(shiftSessions.Where(x => x.Id == (int)s.ParentSessionId));
        cluster.Add(familySessions); //if cluster doesn't contain familySessions
    }
}
```

My attempt following Blindy's answer:

```
List<Session> shiftSessions = new List<Session>();
Dictionary<int, Session> dict = new Dictionary<int, Session>();
HashSet<Session> sessions = new HashSet<Session>();

foreach (var s in shiftSessions)
{
    dict.Add(s.Id, s);
    sessions.Add(s);
}

foreach (var s in sessions)
{
    List<Session> familySessions = new List<Session>();
    List<Session> singleSessions = new List<Session>();

    if (s.ParentSessionId == null)
    {
        if (shiftSessions.Any(x => x.ParentSessionId == s.Id))
        {
            familySessions.Add(s);
            familySessions.AddRange(shiftSessions.Where(x => x.ParentSessionId == s.Id));
            cluster.Add(s.Id, s); //if cluster doesn't contain familySessions

            sessions.Remove(s);
            foreach (var parent in shiftSessions.Where(x => x.ParentSessionId == s.Id))
            {
                sessions.Remove(parent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            singleSessions.Add(s);
            cluster.Add(singleSessions); //if cluster doesn't contain singleSessions

            res.Remove(s);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        familySessions.Add(s);
        familySessions.AddRange(shiftSessions.Where(x => x.Id == (int)s.ParentSessionId));
        cluster.Add(s.Id, s); //if cluster doesn't contain familySessions

        sessions.Remove(s);
        foreach (var child in shiftSessions.Where(x => x.Id == (int)s.ParentSessionId))
        {
            sessions.Remove(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654056/group-list-of-objects-based-on-property-using-linq

Comment: What was this line `var cluster;` intended to do? It is not legal C#... I also don't see how your code implements what you described - can you try to provide example data and answers? What data structure do you expect your answer to have?

Comment: @NetMage The 'cluster' is meant to represent the list of collections. It's not legal C#, unfortunately, I didn't know how to represent this type of collection/data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need two data structures:

1. A `Dictionary<int, Session>` to map ids to sessions quickly
2. A `HashSet<Session>` to hold sessions still to process

You fist push everything into the set, then while the set isn't empty you take one out and start a new cluster with it, then recursively do the same for its parents and children, as well as the cluster's parents and children.

The cluster is also a set, to not allow duplicates.

Edit: a quick and dirty implementation is something like this (complexity is approximately `O(n logn)`:

```
    struct T
    {
        public int Id, ParentId;

        public T(int id, int parentId) { Id = id; ParentId = parentId; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is T t && Id == t.Id && ParentId == t.ParentId;
        public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(Id, ParentId);

        public static bool operator ==(T left, T right) => left.Equals(right);
        public static bool operator !=(T left, T right) => !(left == right);
    }

    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        var input = new[] { new T(0, -1), new T(1, -1), new T(2, 0), new T(3, 2), new T(4, 2), new T(5, 1) };

        var inputSet = input.ToHashSet();
        var parentLookup = input.ToDictionary(w => w.Id, w => w.ParentId);
        var results = new List<List<T>>();

        while (inputSet.Any())
        {
            var val = inputSet.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ParentId == -1);
            if (val.ParentId == 0) break;           // done

            // remove from the active inputs and add to the result cluster
            inputSet.Remove(val);
            List<T> cluster;
            results.Add(cluster = new List<T> { val });
            var clusterIds = new HashSet<int> { val.Id };

            // add all children for the cluster elements until no more are available
            while (true)
            {
                var children = inputSet.Where(w => clusterIds.Contains(w.ParentId)).ToList();
                if (!children.Any()) break;

                children.ForEach(w => { inputSet.Remove(w); cluster.Add(w); clusterIds.Add(w.Id); });
            }
        }

        results.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(", ", r.Select(w => w.Id))}"));
    }
```

Result:

```
0, 2, 3, 4
1, 5
```

[Online showcase](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7gJsHj)

Comment: Like this:

Dictionary<int, Session> dict = new Dictionary<int, Session>();
foreach (var s in shiftSessions)
{
 dict.Add(s.Id, s);   
}

How would this help?

Comment: You need to get the children and parents for each node in your cluster, and this dictionary allows you to look it up. In graph theory this is the edge vector, since what you're doing is essentially graph walking.

Comment: The issue I have is understanding how to 'group' together the parent/children and having a collection of the groups.

Comment: That's what the algorithm I described above does. Did you try implementing it? Or do you have a specific question that's stopping you that I can help with? I could obviously write it for you, but this screams homework to me, and you know the whole set a man on fire idiom lol

Comment: Aha, it's not homework, it's a work issue. I've posted my changes in the OP. I'm unsure how to use the `dict` variable.

Comment: I edited in a working example implementation of a graph walking algorithm with your input data structure, let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Also writing it, I apparently didn't need the parent dictionary, I used a set of cluster ids instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new type to contain a `Session` with its Children:

```
public class SessionWithChildren {
    public Session session;
    public List<SessionWithChildren> children = new List<SessionWithChildren>();
}
```

Create a map from `Id` to a `SessionWithChildren`:

```
var sessionLookup = sessions.ToDictionary(s => s.Id, s => new SessionWithChildren() { session = s });
```

Group all the sessions together by parent:

```
var children = sessionLookup.GroupBy(skvp => skvp.Value.session.ParentSessionId, skvp => skvp.Value);
```

Now you can go through the children that have parents and assign them to the proper parent:

```
foreach (var childgroup in children.Where(sg => sg.Key.HasValue)) {
    foreach (var child in childgroup) {
        sessionLookup[child.session.ParentSessionId.Value].children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Finally, the sessions without parents form the root of your tree:

```
var ans = children.First(sg => !sg.Key.HasValue).ToList();
```