# C# MVC Return List in Formatted Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Have a list that returns in Json but want to format it as below. Can't figure out for the life of me why I can't seem to get it formatted right.

```
[{
    "AppFormName": "TFB Test Application",
    "Questions": [{
        "QuestionName": "How old are you?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "QuestionName": "Where are you from?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    }]
},
{
    "AppFormName": "HLL",
    "Questions": [{
        "QuestionName": "How old are you?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "QuestionName": "Where are you from?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "QuestionName": "What Game are you applying for?",
        "QuestionType": 2
    },
    {
        "QuestionName": "Do you agree to the clan rules",
        "QuestionType": 3
    }]
}]
```

This is what my code produces currently:

```
[
    {
        "AppFormName": "TFB Test Application",
        "QuestionName": "How old are you?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "AppFormName": "TFB Test Application",
        "QuestionName": "Where are you from?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "AppFormName": "HLL",
        "QuestionName": "How old are you?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "AppFormName": "HLL",
        "QuestionName": "Where are you from?",
        "QuestionType": 1
    },
    {
        "AppFormName": "HLL",
        "QuestionName": "What Game are you applying for?",
        "QuestionType": 2
    },
    {
        "AppFormName": "HLL",
        "QuestionName": "Do you agree to the clan rules",
        "QuestionType": 3
    }
]
```

This is my controller where I'm trying to serialize the results;

```
public ActionResult AccessToken(string authorizationCode)
{
    UserFunctions.AccessToken(authorizationCode);
    var results = UserFunctions.userApplications;

    return Json(results , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Model:

```
public class UserApplications
{
    public string AppFormName { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public int QuestionType { get; set; }
}
```

Function to get data;

```
   public static List<Models.UserApplications> GetUserApplications(string ClientId)
    {
        userApplications.Clear();

        var getUserApplications = getUserApplicationsSQL;

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(dataConn))
        {
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(getUserApplications, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiscordClientID", ClientId);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var u = new Models.UserApplications
                        {
                            AppFormName = dr["AppFormName"].ToString(),
                            QuestionName = dr["QuestionName"].ToString(),
                            QuestionType = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("TypeID")),
                        };
                        userApplications.Add(u);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return userApplications;
    }
```

Comment: `Json()` will already serialize objects to json, also how to format json is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters), but your format doesn't seem to be a standard format, so unless you want to write your own formatter i'd suggest `WriteIndented `

Comment: You're double-serialising your data. Please realise that `return Json(...` will automatically serialise whatever you provide it. So if you provide it pre-seralised JSON, it will attempt to serialise it again, resulting in junk. Just provide the `results` object direct to this method, you don't need to involve JsonSerializer manually.

Comment: @ADyson was initially doing it that way, but couldn't get it to format in the way I required, so tried the way posted above.

Comment: I see. Well the way you've attempted won't improve anything, as we've explained. All you're doing is making the same process happen twice. Revert to your first attempt please. Then, please show us exactly what JSON that produces. And lastly please show us what actual JSON you want. Your expected result sample now is really unclear because it's not valid JSON. It's better to show us a valid sample so we know exactly what you mean.

Comment: P.S. it's unclear how the GetUserData method is related to any of this - it doesn't seem to be used in your action method. We don't know what `UserFunctions.userApplications` does, though, or what exactly it returns, so that could be the missing link?

Comment: @ADyson the `UserFunctions.userApplications` is the list of data that's passed to the controller from my function. I've updated my JSON section so how I'd like it displayed, I hope that's in valid JSON

Comment: Yes that's now valid JSON for your desired output. But can also also please show (a useful sample of) the results you get right now, as previously requested? I'm guessing that each AppFormName actually has multiple questions returned from it potentially, so you are getting multiple rows in the SQL results for each AppFormName? if so then you're going to have to manually process the results into a different class structure, to get the JSON structure you want when it's serialised. But the structure you've posted will only actually still support one appform, and one question per appform!

Comment: BTW the userApplications thing makes more sense now, you've changed the method name, thanks.

Comment: Did you really mean you want a structure something like `[{
  "AppFormName": "App1",
     "Questions": [{
         "QuestionName": "What is your favourite colour?",
         "QuestionType": "1"
      },{
         "QuestionName": "What is your favourite fruit?",
         "QuestionType": "2"
      }]
}, {
  "AppFormName": "App2",
     "Questions": [{
         "QuestionName": "What is your favourite band?",
         "QuestionType": "1"
      },{
         "QuestionName": "What is your favourite animal?",
         "QuestionType": "3"
      }]
}]` perhaps?

Comment: That would potentially support mutiple appforms, and multiple questions within each appform, if required. Do you need that ability? Or is one appform with one question sufficient?

Comment: @ADyson in answer to your question and example you gave, yes that is spot on what I need. A user could have multiple AppForms, and there can be multiple questions under each appform

Comment: @ADyson this is what I get currently `[{"AppFormName":"TFB Test Application","QuestionName":"How old are you?","QuestionType":1},{"AppFormName":"TFB Test Application","QuestionName":"Where are you from?","QuestionType":1},{"AppFormName":"HLL","QuestionName":"How old are you?","QuestionType":1},{"AppFormName":"HLL","QuestionName":"Where are you from?","QuestionType":1},{"AppFormName":"HLL","QuestionName":"What Game are you applying for?","QuestionType":2},{"AppFormName":"HLL","QuestionName":"Do you agree to the clan rules","QuestionType":3}]`

Comment: To make it a lot clearer for everybody I added those structures to the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need code to translate from your existing data structure into one which will produced the desired JSON structure. This can be accomplished relatively easily using Linq. And then you need to return that list in your action method:

```
public ActionResult AccessToken(string authorizationCode)
{
    UserFunctions.AccessToken(authorizationCode);
    var results = UserFunctions.userApplications;

    var appFormList = results.GroupBy(s => s.AppFormName).Select(g => new
    {
      AppFormName = g.Key, Questions = g.Select(a => new
      {
        a.QuestionName, 
        a.QuestionType
      })
    });

    return Json(appFormList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sRIy72

(Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654056/group-list-of-objects-based-on-property-using-linq) for the idea to use Linq.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved by Grouping:

```
public ActionResult AccessToken(string authorizationCode)
{
    UserFunctions.AccessToken(authorizationCode);
    List<UserApplications> results = UserFunctions.userApplications;
    var data = from p in results 
           group p by p.AppFormName into g
           select new { AppFormName = g.Key, Questions = g.Select(x=> new { QuestionName = x.QuestionName, QuestionType = x.QuestionType}).ToList() };

    return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: good attempt but it doesn't quite produce exactly the right output - check it carefully compared with the sample in the question. Also, apart from the different style of Linq syntax it's basically the same idea as I've already posted.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need an extra model or Method, It can be handled with anonymous type, Check the above function it produces the exact result as stated in the question.

Comment: Having an extra method and a strong type is good encapsulation - it makes the code reusable. That's the reason I did it like that. It's good programming practice, in general. But I agree it could be shortened for the purpose of this example. Your new version will work correctly though, yes.