# Is there a way to group all object by a common property value, without knowing that value?

Tags: c#, list, grouping

If I have a House object, and I want to group all the ones that are the same color, is there a way to do this without knowing the actual color?

For example

| Houses | Color |
| --- | --- |
| HouseA | Yellow |
| HouseB | Green |
| HouseC | Yellow |
| HouseD | Green |

In this case, **HouseA and HouseC** would be grouped into 1 list, and **HouseB and HouseD** would be grouped into another list.

How can I group these houses without knowing the colors?

Comment: I can clearly see the colors, what do you mean with "without knowing the colors"? *"I want to group all the ones that are the same color"* - any attempt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group List of Objects based on Property using Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654056/group-list-of-objects-based-on-property-using-linq)

Comment: You don't need to know the value of color in order to group by that, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results#group-by-single-property-example

Comment: Right now, I could group it by looping through the list of House Objects and collecting ones that are Yellow or Green. But can I group by using a condition that doesn't include Yellow or Green in it? Otherwise, I would probably just get a distinct list of all color values in the array of object and for each color value, group objects that have that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, use the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) LINQ method, like so:

```cs
List<House> houses = ... // Your houses here
var grouped = houses.GroupBy(x => x.Color);

// grouped is an'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, House>>' and you can access the properties like so:

foreach (var grouping in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grouping.Key);
    foreach (var house in grouping)
        Console.WriteLine(house.Name);
}
```

[`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-5.0) documentation.

If, instead, you want to turn this into a dictionary for fast and easy lookups, you can also easily do this like so:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<House>> housesByColor = grouped.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
```

Check out my [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/410orO)